# Can i get earth quake data from api services?

Tags: data, united-states

I am working with environmental application and i am willing to add information about Earth Quake.

If Other apis like openweather,accuweather etc have services for earthquake, please let me know.

(Lets just forget about how to use or where to use.)

There are bunch of apis but they are not free.

Is there any free api services for earth quake updates?

Comment: Try looking at Usgs?

Comment: expanding on suggestion by @iant, try [the USGS feeds](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The British Geological Survey provide feeds of *recent* earthquakes from the last 30 days as both GeoRSS and Kml:

[Recent Worldwide Earthquakes Feeds](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/data/services/georss.html)

- [GeoRSS Recent Earthquakes](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/feeds/WorldSeismology.xml)
- [KML Recent Earthquakes](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/feeds/WorldSeismology.kml)

Data from these feeds is available under an [Open Data Licence](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/).  A [historical earthquake search](http://www.earthquakes.bgs.ac.uk/earthquakes/dataSearch.html) is also available however I am unsure of the terms of use.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

http://www.emsc-csem.org/Earthquake/

EMSC RSS Feeds:

http://www.emsc-csem.org/service/rss/

I'm not sure of their terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try [Earthquake Reports](http://www.earthquake-reports.com) for JSON/RSS feeds.

You can also see a very basic earthquake map I threw together using this data [here](https://vast-river-5785.herokuapp.com)